# For each and If condition fails

Tags: scala, for-loop, if-statement, amazon-s3, foreach

I am trying to generate s3 path for every marketplace and if path exists run the code. However, the code doesn't seem to read the path, getting error "ResourceNotFoundException". Apparently, it does not satisfy the if condition and comes out of the loop.

```
val rootBucket1 = "s3://bucket1/"
val rootBucket2 = "s3://bucket2/"
val marketplacesToRead: Vector[Marketplace] = Marketplace.values.filter(marketplace => params.regions.contains(marketplace.outputRegion)).toVector

--> marketplacesToRead is a list of marketplaces

marketplacesToRead.forEach((marketplaceId) => {
            val Path1 = rootBucket1 + s"marketplace_id=${marketplaceId.id}/" 
            val Path2 = rootBucket2 + s"marketplace_id=${marketplaceId.id}/" 

           if (doesS3PathExist(Path1) && doesS3PathExist(Path2)) {

// execute code and write it to a s3 location

}
})

def doesS3PathExist(path: String): Boolean = {
            FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), new Configuration).exists(new Path(path))
        }
```

Comment: Could you add more debugging details? Does this code throw an exception? Are you sure that you can hit the `s3` path using that code or even from that server? what is the expected input and output? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help to improve your question.